# How can I get cygwin to disable fortran?

Tags: cygwin, gdal, hdf

I'm trying to install the HDF4 library for GDAL using Cygwin, and the readme instructs me to configure the source code as such:

```
./configure <--disable-fortran> 
                   --enable-hdf4-xdr
                   --with-zlib=/path_to_ZLIB_install_directory 
                   --with-jpeg=/path_to_JPEG_install_directory 
                   <--with-szlib=/path_to_SZIP_install_directory>
                   --prefix=/path_to_HDF4_install_directory
```

However, I can't seem to get the <--disable-fortran> part right. It returns an error when executed:

```
-bash: --disable-fortran: No such file or directory
```

What am I doing wrong? I'm a novice to programming.

Edit:

This is the link to the readme: https://support.hdfgroup.org/ftp/HDF/HDF_Current/src/unpacked/release_notes/INSTALL_CYGWIN.txt

Comment: In the future, please provide links to instructions (such as the referenced readme here).  I can say that (unquoted) less-than and greater-than (<) characters are detected as pipes by the shell, so your command is interpreted as something like "start the configure command, and pass it the values found in --disable-fortran.  Pass the output to nowhere."  I expect, but do not know, that in the code you show above, the < and > indicate values that are optional.  Maybe the readme clarifies this?

Answer (score 0):

as Dennis wrote, you are misunderstanding the meaning of <..> . In this context
they are optional not mandatory configuration

```
 ./configure <--disable-fortran> 
              --enable-hdf4-xdr
              --with-zlib=/path_to_ZLIB_install_directory 
              --with-jpeg=/path_to_JPEG_install_directory 
              <--with-szlib=/path_to_SZIP_install_directory>
              --prefix=/path_to_HDF4_install_directory
```

so one possible way is to include the first and not the second:

```
    ./configure --disable-fortran 
               --enable-hdf4-xdr
               --with-zlib=/path_to_ZLIB_install_directory 
               --with-jpeg=/path_to_JPEG_install_directory 
               --prefix=/path_to_HDF4_install_directory
```

Comment: Thank you very much.

I tried executing --disable-fortran on Cygwin, but it returned the above error I mentioned. Is there another way of disabling Fortran on cygwin? Was there a change in the command to execute disabling fortran?

Comment: `--disable-fortran` is an option of configure . It is not a command stand alone